# How to change dropbox_uploader.sh account set up

Tags: shell, dropbox

I'm using the script of Dropbox Upload (https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader) and the first time I set up to transfer file from my Dropbox account but now I wanna change the account.

I try remove the script and download again to try reconfigure, but it didn't work.

Any idea how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running script's `unlink` command:

```
sh ./dropbox-uploader.sh unlink
```

Or remove the configuration file (`unlink` command does the same internally):

```
rm ~/.dropbox_uploader
```

Comment: Thank you! I run it and work, but I don't used the "sh". (I used "./dropbox-uploader.sh unlink").